# Angular2+ Input element with Template Element Reference not updating

Tags: angular, typescript, variables, angular-ngmodel, angular-forms

I've a Form for password change and the "Save password" button is disabled  as long as the new password and it's repetition is not equal.
To keep the controller 'clean' I've  mapped a `Template Element Reference` to the repetition `input`.

```
 <form>
     <input [(ngModel)]="newPassword"
            type="password"
            name="new-password"
            id="new-password">

     <input type="password"
            name="new-password-repeat"
            id="new-password-repeat"
            #passwordRepeatInput>

     <!-- This is the output -->
     <pre>{{passwordRepeatInput.value}}</pre>

    <button [disabled]="!!newPassword && passwordRepeatInput.value"
             class="btn btn-primary">
  Save password
</button>
```

Now unexpected things happen. When I change the value of the repetition field the output won't change. But once I change another input within the form the output becomes the value of the input element — So it does not behalf like an element having the `[(ngModel)]` attribute assigned.

Once I specify a new model property in my controller and map it to the repetition field via `[(ngModel)]` the Template Element Reference is working and changes the output whenever the input value changes.

```
 <input type="password"
        name="new-password-repeat"
        id="new-password-repeat"
        [(ngModel)]="passwordRepeatModelVal" // This solves the problem
        #passwordRepeatInput>
```

But Is there a way to establish the expected behavior without having unnecessary properties in the controller?

Comment: I don't understand. What's the difference between calling the component property you're binding to `newPasswordRepeat` or `passwordRepeatModelVal`? What's `newPasswordRepeat` then, in the first case?

Comment: For `passwordRepeatModelVal` I have to decare a property in the controller but using a template reference `#passwordRepeatInput` there shouldn't be a need for this declaration

Comment: But in your first case, `newPasswordRepeat` is not a template reference, is it? What does it reference?

Comment: If `newPasswordRepeat` is not defined, then `passwordRepeatInput.value` is always the same (probably an empty string).

Comment: The # char and yes he model assignment is too much here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view should also update correctly if you apply the `ngModel` directive by itself to the repeat `input` element, without binding it to a property:

```
<input type="password"
       name="new-password-repeat"
       id="new-password-repeat"
       ngModel
       #passwordRepeatInput>
```

See [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9aoicc).